# What is the meaning of this symbol?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[This symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRgCO.png)

$(\vec r - \vec r_j)\cdot \vec n_j = 0\,(j = \overline{1,3})$

I'm referring to the $j = \overline{1,3}$ part. It looks like an ordered pair but with a dash on top. 
What am I supposed to do here ?
Replace vector Rj with 1 and 3 respectively?

Comment: I can almost make out the symbols, is it possible to provide a worse resolution image?

Comment: One to three presumably. Pleae typeset the formula.

Comment: My guess is it means "For all $j\in \{1,2,3\}$", but I haven't seen this before.

Comment: I suppose that it means that the "vector formula" is a "triple" : one with $r_1$, one with $r_2$ and one with $r_3$...